# Is attribute [Produces("application/json")] enough to prevent all xss attacks in WebApi&ReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, xss, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing SPA using ASP.NET Core and ReactJS.

In some places of application users have an opportunity to create comments, that will be shown everyone. So I have string inputs in controllers, and I save data 'as is' in database.

I've added attribute [Produces("application/json")] for each controller - to return json as results (I don't use server-side render).

My question: should I additionally encode input data (before saving in DB or before sending to user) - or this attribute automatically encodes all strings (before sending to user) and I won't have any chance have XSS attack in my application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) specify

> A filter that specifies the expected Type the action will return and
>   the supported response content types. The ContentTypes value is used
>   to set ContentTypes

The Produces attribute will only define what the action/method will produce, it will not encode any input string

Comment: Adding to this answer, react does offer some protection against XSS, sanitizing all inputs by default (except for styles) before using them in a component, as explained here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3473. It's not bulletproof, but it's an extra layer you can count on